# Select non-contiguous cells within a T.Test

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I think that it is not possible after some search, but here is my question:

I have a row of values, which correspond to a quantity we calculate every day. We alternate the experiments between product A and product B.

Now, I want to run student tests on the averages of 3 consecutive experiments, on product A versus product B. A toy example can be found below:

[image]

I would like to run a `T.Test` to compare the sets of values (B2,D2,F2) to (C2,E2,G2). However, nothing seems to work, at least not the following:

`=T.Test((B2,D2,F2);(C2,E2,G2);2;1)`

`=T.Test((B2;D2;F2);(C2;E2;G2);2;1)`

`=T.Test({"B2";"D2";"F2"};{"C2";"E2";"G2"};2;1)`

Note that I was able to get my test results by reorganizing the data so that the ranges are contiguous, but this has definitely made be curious to see if there is a solution.

Comment: Not sure if there could be something easier, but I immediately thought about stacking. Have a go with `=T.TEST(HSTACK(B2,D2,F2),HSTACK(C2,E2,G2),2,1)`

Comment: It seems to give me a `#Name?` error

Comment: Shame, you must have not got acces to this function just yet then. Try: `=T.TEST(INDEX(B2:G2,{1,3,5}),INDEX(B2:G2,{2,4,6}),2,1)` to mimic this.

Comment: Yes I just saw that :/ The mimic version works like a charm, maybe you can post this as an answer and I can accept it. This question does not seem to be a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those with access to `HSTACK()` (or `VSTACK()` for that matter), try:

```
=T.TEST(HSTACK(B2,D2,F2),HSTACK(C2,E2,G2),2,1)
```

If not available, try:

```
=T.TEST(INDEX(B2:G2,{1,3,5}),INDEX(B2:G2,{2,4,6}),2,1)
```

---

**EDIT:** for those with older versions of Excel, as per @JosWoolley you'd indeed need to pursuade Excel to use arrays:

```
=T.TEST(INDEX(B2:G2,N(IF(1,{1,3,5}))),INDEX(B2:G2,N(IF(1,{2,4,6}))),2,1)
```

Comment: Though for pre-O365 versions, `INDEX` requires extra coercion to generate an array.

Comment: @JosWoolley, valuable comment. Thanks for that.

Comment: and if this is a growing database you could also implement filter to not have to manually add cells: `=T.TEST(FILTER(2:2,3:3="A"),FILTER(2:2,3:3="B"),2,1)`